# Lagrange Multipliers: find points farthest/closest to a point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Find the points of the ellipse:

$$\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}=1$$

which are closest to and farthest from the point $(1,1)$.

I use the method of the Lagrange Multipliers by setting:

$$f(x,y)=(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2$$

(no need for the root since maximizing one maximizes the other)

And $$g(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}-1=0$$ the constraint.

We get:

$$x-1=λx/9$$           and           $$2y-2=λy/2$$

I don't know where to go from there. I tried finding $x$ and $y$ alone and then plugging their values in the constraint $g(x,y)=0$ but I get a really complicated equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$\mathcal{L}(x,y,\lambda)=f(x,y)+\lambda g(x,y)=(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+\lambda \left(\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}-1\right) $$

Then:

$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x}=2(x-1)+\frac{2x\lambda}{9}=0 \implies x=\frac{9}{9+\lambda}$

$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y}=2(y-1)+\frac{\lambda y}{2}=0 \implies y=\frac{4}{4+\lambda}$

$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda}= \frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}-1=0$

so $\implies \frac{\left(\frac{9}{9+\lambda}\right)^2}{9}+\frac{\left(\frac{4}{4+\lambda}\right)^2}{4}=1$

$\implies \frac{9}{(9+\lambda)^2}+\frac{4}{(4+\lambda)^2}=1$

Then solve for $\lambda$ (not easy) then plug in value to obtain $x=\frac{9}{9+\lambda}$ and $y=\frac{4}{4+\lambda}$ that are required

Comment: I don't get it. Do we need to add a third function?

Comment: http://www.cv.titech.ac.jp/~hiro-lab/lecture/civil_analy/09note3.pdf

Comment: Ok I actually got to the same part as you:

$$9/(9+λ)^2+4/(4+λ)^2=1$$ (it's the complicated equation I was talking about)
How do you solve that?

Also I got $$x=9/9-λ$$ and $$y=4/4-λ$$ does that change anything? I followed exactly what they did in my book so I don't see why we are getting different results

Comment: Someone else is going to have to check my answer. I doubt im wrong but solving for $\lambda$ is way to hard for pedagogical purposes

Comment: You havent made this question up have you?

Comment: No it's in my booklet, I got to the same equation which seemed too hard for me so I thought I went wrong somewhere. Let me try to solve it with wolframalpha.

Comment: $λ=-12.096$ and $λ=-1.79992$

Comment: Your lecturer hasnt thought this through very well

Comment: Anyways, does it change anything that I found $y=4/4-λ$ and $x=9/9-λ$ while you found a $+$ for them? I've been using the book's tactic and getting correct answers on other exercises.

Comment: Post the correct answers for this question then...

Comment: I think it's just a sign convention for $\lambda $

Comment: Well those are the λ that wolframalpha gave me but I don't have a solution to the problem.

Comment: You have everything you need now

Comment: Two values of lambda ... plug it in

Comment: (1.3,1.8) and (-2.9,-0.5) (approximately) Thank you so much!

Comment: I actually get the same lambdas but with a minus sign with my technique, so I guess it all came down to solving that nasty equation. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Sorry it's my 3rd time or so on this site. Do I just check the tick or something else needs to be done?

Comment: Up vote answers you like. Accept the best (or quickest) answer that helped you

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$ f(x,y)=(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2 $$

$$ g(x,y)= \left(\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4 } \right) $$

$$ -\lambda =\dfrac{ \dfrac{\partial f }{\partial x } }{\dfrac{\partial g }{\partial x } } =\dfrac{ \dfrac{\partial f }{\partial y } }{\dfrac{\partial g }{\partial y } }. $$

Comment: $g$ isnt correct here